# The first row of my SQLite Database is not getting fetched and displayed in my RecyclerView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is my `dbmanager` class:

```
public class dbmanager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String sgpa_table="create table Sgpa (sname text, semester text, sgpa  int,percent int, schemes int, primary key(sname,semester,schemes))";


    public dbmanager(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, "Student", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(sgpa_table);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public Cursor fetch_data1() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "Select*FROM Sgpa" ;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        if (cursor != null) {
           cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

This is my `Adapter` class:

```
public class adapter_sgpa extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter_sgpa.Viewholder> {

    ArrayList<POJO> sgpaArrayList;

    public adapter_sgpa(ArrayList<POJO> sgpaArrayList) {
        this.sgpaArrayList = sgpaArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public adapter_sgpa.Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View listitem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_sgpa, parent, false);
        return new Viewholder(listitem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull adapter_sgpa.Viewholder holder, int position) {


        POJO sgpa= sgpaArrayList.get(position);
        holder.sname.setText(sgpa.getSname());
        holder.semester.setText(sgpa.getSemester());
        holder.sgpa.setText(Integer.toString(sgpa.getSgpa()));
        holder.percent.setText(Integer.toString(sgpa.getPercent()));
        holder.schemes.setText(Integer.toString(sgpa.getSchemes()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sgpaArrayList.size();
    }

    public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView sname, semester, sgpa, percent, schemes;
        //ImageButton btndelete1;

        public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            sname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            semester = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.semester);
            sgpa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textV);
            percent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textVw);
            schemes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.scheme1);
          //  btndelete1 = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btndelete1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is sgpa_frag which is like my main class:

```
public class sgpa_frag extends Fragment {
    //View view;
    RecyclerView recyclerview;
    adapter_sgpa ac;
    TextView else2;

    ArrayList<POJO> sgpaArrayList;

    public sgpa_frag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sgpa_frag, container, false);
        recyclerview= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rc1);
        else2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.else2);
        sgpaArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
        ac= new adapter_sgpa(sgpaArrayList);
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,true));
        recyclerview.setAdapter(ac);

        Fetchdata1();

        return view;
    }

    private void Fetchdata1()
    {
        dbmanager db= new dbmanager(getContext());

        Cursor cursor= db.fetch_data1();

        if (cursor!= null){

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                //ModelDetail cd= new ModelDetail(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4));

                POJO pj= new POJO();
                pj.setSname(cursor.getString(0));
                pj.setSemester(cursor.getString(1));
                pj.setSgpa(cursor.getInt(2));
                pj.setPercent(cursor.getInt(3));
                pj.setSchemes(cursor.getInt(4));
                sgpaArrayList.add(pj);
            }

            ac= new adapter_sgpa(sgpaArrayList);
            recyclerview.setAdapter(ac);
        }
        else{
            else2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

The first row of my **SQLite Database** is not getting fetched and displayed in my `RecyclerView`.
The other rows are getting displayed but only the **first one** is not getting displayed.
Can someone point me out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this part of your code in `Fetchdata1()`:

```
if (cursor!= null){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
..................................
```

remove `cursor.moveToFirst();`
because `cursor.moveToNext()` will advance the cursor's index to the 2nd row and the 1st row will not be added to the list.
Also inside `fetch_data1()` inside `dbmanager` remove this:

```
if (cursor != null) {
   cursor.moveToFirst();
}
```